# How can I flag up documents in a library that are drafts (minor versions 0.1)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I would like to flag up all minor versions of documents in a document library. It's probably one for a calculated field but I am having trouble figureing out how to do it?

Basically what I want is to say if the version column = anything but *.0 then give me a value. Once I have a value I can make a view to show everything in that value.

Any Ideas? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can use the JSLink for this. You can change the rendering of document list item using it.

Comment: Explain how and provide an example please.

Answer (score 1):

Programming a Client-Side-Rendering script and attaching it with JSLink, so the Version field is presented different is the 2013 solution.
That takes some scripting

If you read this: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How (and read the Pros & Cons!)

and paste this Formula **in a Calculacted Column set to datatype=Number**
(*you can leave out the original Version column from the View*)

```
= [Version] 
&"<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
&"var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode}"
&IF(  FIND(".0",[Version])   ,   ""  ,  "row.style.backgroundColor='pink';"  )
&"}"">"
```

It should color any row **not** containing a x.0 Version pink,
and work just everywhere this Calculated Column is displayed

This is all Client Side so you can't use View Filtering.

You could however change it to:

```
&IF(FIND(".0",[Version]), "row.style.display='none';" , "row.style.backgroundColor='pink';" )
```

and all those x.0 Rows will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this but it's certainly not the most fool proof and wont work in every situation

I created a view and set it so it only shows items/documents that have .1, .2, .3 etc in the version column. 
[image]

This is OK if you limit the amount or minor versions, I am sure there is a better way to achieve this. If anyone knows please comment or submit a better answer.